# How to DC bias op amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm trying to bias an op amp, [I'm reading this document for reference.](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/media-arts-and-sciences/mas-836-sensor-technologies-for-interactive-environments-spring-2011/readings/MITMAS_836S11_read02_bias.pdf)

I'm reading along and it makes perfect sense until section "How to Select Component Values:"

They want to amplify a signal with amplitude of 1V going from 2V to 1V to put it on 0-5V swing.

The gain needs to be -5 but then they introduce "operating point" and never define it.

They say operating point can be set to either (2V, 0V) or (1V, 5V.)

What do those pairs even mean? I stared at the document for good 20 minutes, still can't understand that it means.

Comment: draw on X&Y axis, the expected input voltage and the expected output voltage. Label the pairs, as in (2v => 0v), (1v=> +5v) or whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

The example they're considering is you have a signal that swings between 1 and 2 V, and you want to scale and offset it to get an output signal that swings between 5 V and 0 V.

So you could consider the operating point to be when the input is 2 V and the output is 0 V , which they call "(2 V, 0 V)". Then the input signal would always be a negative voltage added to the 2 v operating point.

Or you could consider the operating point to be when the input is 2 V and the output is 5 V, which they call "(1 V, 5 V)". Then the input signal would always be a positive voltage added to the 1 V operating point.

This nomenclature is not common, and you shouldn't worry about ever seeing it again.

Comment: I think it's the other way around in their example, input signal is from +2V to +1V and they want output to be 0V to +5V but it makes sense, thanks!

Comment: @user1078719, you're right, edited.